# str_replace of html content with php

Tags: php, html, regex, str-replace

I have this code:

```
$str = 'di &lt;a href="http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/author/redazione-la/#C" style="color:#006699; text-decoration:none;"&gt;VARIABLE NAME&lt;/a&gt;'.
                '&lt;br&gt;'.
                '&lt;strong&gt;POST TITLE&lt;/strong&gt;'.
                '&lt;br&gt;'.
                '&lt;br&gt;';
                $content=str_replace($str, "", $content);
```

With it I would remove this content from RSS description like this:

***NOTE: $STR IS COMPOSED BY A VARIABLE NAME and A POST TITLE that change for each item!***

```
&lt;img src="http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/img/fico-balo.JPG" width="280" height="94" align="left" style="margin-right:10px;" hspace="10" &gt; 
&lt;div style="margin-right:10px;" &gt;
di &lt;a href="http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/author/redazione-la/#C" style="color:#006699; text-decoration:none;"&gt;Redazione Cadoinpiedi.it&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;br&gt;
&lt;strong&gt;La showgirl ha denunciato la coppia per diffamazione&lt;/strong&gt;
&lt;br&gt;
&lt;br&gt;

Raffaella Fico ha querelato i coniugi Balotelli, che rischiano un processo per il reato di diffamazione aggravata, perchÃ© commessa a mezzo stampa. Sulla Gazzetta dello Sport del 27 dicembre scorso i Balotelli avevano scritto una lettera aperta alla modella. &quot;Nostro figlio non Ã¨ quell&apos;essere irresponsabile e senza dignitÃ  che tu... &lt;a href="http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/2013/07/11/raffaella_fico_porta_in_tribunale_i_genitori_di_balotelli.html" style="color:#006699; text-decoration:none;"&gt; Leggi &lt;/a&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;
```

It don't work...what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For one thing, you appear to be concatenating your string using pluses "+" instead of periods "."

Comment: sorry I have edited...I have to delete all the text like $str in $content

Comment: @michele do you know already the variable name and the post title when you get the content back.

Answer (score 0):

your string concatenation is incorrect. its probably causing `$str` to be equal to `0` when passed to the function. use `.` for concatenation.

```
$str = 'di &lt;a href="http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/author/redazione-la/#C";'
     . 'style="color:#006699; text-decoration:none;"&gt;' . $VARNAME . '&lt;/a&gt;' 
     . '&lt;br&gt;' 
     . '&lt;strong&gt;' . $POSTTITLE . '&lt;/strong&gt;' 
     . '&lt;br&gt;' 
     . '&lt;br&gt;';
```

Comment: it's not good because VARIABLE NAME change. it is not a constant.

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand you.

Comment: I don't know POST TITLE and VARNAME

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = substr($content,0,182).substr($content,448);
```

It doesn't fix your code, which is probably a problem with the `+` concatenation as metioned in a comment on your question, however, it should do what you are wanting.

Update to reflect OP question changes:

```
$startPos = stripos($content, "di &lt;");
$endPos = strripos($content, "&lt;br&gt;", $startPos) + 10;
$content = substr($content, 0, $startPos) . substr($content, $endPos);
```

Comment: it's not good because VARIABLE NAME change and it's not ever the same.

Comment: I agree, but your original attempt is just as rigid so I thought it would not matter.

Comment: excuse me I was badly explained

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution which should work for you.

Comment: it is not working well.
I have to remove from di "&lt;" to '&lt;br&gt;'

Answer (score 0):

```
$endPos = stripos($content, "<br>");
                echo "<br><br><br>start:".$startPos."<br><br><br>end". $endPos." <br><br><br>";
                $content = substr($content, $endPos, strlen($content)-1);
                echo "<br><br><br>ecco: ".$content;
```